# Binary To Decimal

Tags: c

The program is suppose to convert binary number to decimal form. Only using `scanf()` and `printf()` library functions. Takes in a `char array` from user ---no prompt outputs decimal form, function must be used with parameter (`char binaryString[]`) after conversion result must be printed out in main. Program does not work don't think I'm converting the binary form to decimal form correctly in function `binaryToDecimal` since i cant use `pow()` I'm lost

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int binaryToDecimal(char binaryString[]) {    
    int c, j = 1, decimalNumber = 0;

    for (binaryString[c = 0]; binaryString[c] > binaryString[33];
         binaryString[++c]) {

        while (binaryString[c] != 0) {
            remainder = binaryString[c] % 10;
            decimalNumber = decimalNumber + remainder * j;
            j = j * 2;
            binaryString[c] = binaryString[c] / 10;
        }
    }
    return decimalNumber;
}

int binaryToDecimalMain() {
    int arraysize = 33;
    char binaryString[arraysize];
    scanf("%32s", binaryString);
    printf("%d",binaryToDecimal(binaryString []);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And your question is...

Comment: It will be better in the long run for you to do your own assignments

Comment: I know I'm not asking anyone to write my code just give me advice because I'm lost

Comment: Your 'for' is not doing what you think it's doing. I think you don't need to use binaryString for initialize the 'c', test if c < 33 and increment the value of 'c'

Comment: 1) You want something closer to `for (c=0; binaryString[c] != '\0'; ++c)`. 2) `while()` is not needed inside the `for()` loop.  3) to convert a `char` that is a digit `'0'` or `'1'` to its integer value, simple subtract `'0'` --> `value = binaryString[c] - '0'`.  4) Think of how you would evaluate a number like "12345" reading only given 1 digit at a time from the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I not give you the algorithm because it's seems that you are learning how to program and it is important to you to learn to discover how to  solve the problems that are given to you.But I can give you some hints:

- use binaryString only to compare with '0' or '1'. Don't try to make any operations like '%' on it.
- iterate on the binaryString character by character (no `while` inside `for` [this is only for this case, there some algorithm that is necessary to do something like this])
- your logic to convert is on the right track

Also you should call your main function `main`.

Comment: yes!!! thank you I'm one week into learning C so thanks for understanding all I wanted was some advice on where to go

Comment: thanks again cannot believe how happy I am my code works now yay your suggestions were awesome

Comment: Great! =) As I said, you were on the right track. You had the hardest and most important part that is how to solve the problem. I just help you with the C, which is only a tool> Keep up with the good work!